# Yup: Array error message sometimes has a string, sometimes a numeric index

Tags: yup

Trying to validate an array of strings with these rules. The array has numeric indexes, yet the first rule returns a string index, making it difficult to map to error messages. What am I doing wrong?

```
  estpos: Yup.object({
    stateSpecific: Yup.array(Yup.string()
        .required('No state selected')
        .test('dupe-state', 'Duplicate state', (value) => countStates(value) <= 1),
    )
  }),
```

Array being validated: `["","CA","CA"]`

Result (notice the double quotes in the first path)

```
[
    {
        "value": "",
        "path": "estpos.stateSpecific[\"0\"]",
        "type": "required",
        "errors": [
            "No state selected"
        ],
        "params": {
            "value": "",
            "originalValue": "",
            "path": "estpos.stateSpecific[\"0\"]",
            "spec": {
                "strip": false,
                "strict": false,
                "abortEarly": true,
                "recursive": true,
                "nullable": false,
                "optional": false,
                "coerce": true
            }
        },
        "inner": [],
        "name": "ValidationError",
        "message": "No state selected"
    },
    {
        "value": "CA",
        "path": "estpos.stateSpecific[1]",
        "type": "dupe-state-estpos",
        "errors": [
            "Duplicate state"
        ],
        "params": {
            "value": "CA",
            "originalValue": "CA",
            "path": "estpos.stateSpecific[1]",
            "spec": {
                "strip": false,
                "strict": false,
                "abortEarly": true,
                "recursive": true,
                "nullable": false,
                "optional": false,
                "coerce": true
            }
        },
        "inner": [],
        "name": "ValidationError",
        "message": "Duplicate state"
    },
    {
        "value": "CA",
        "path": "estpos.stateSpecific[2]",
        "type": "dupe-state-estpos",
        "errors": [
            "Duplicate state"
        ],
        "params": {
            "value": "CA",
            "originalValue": "CA",
            "path": "estpos.stateSpecific[2]",
            "spec": {
                "strip": false,
                "strict": false,
                "abortEarly": true,
                "recursive": true,
                "nullable": false,
                "optional": false,
                "coerce": true
            }
        },
        "inner": [],
        "name": "ValidationError",
        "message": "Duplicate state"
    }
]
```